# Align text above material design icon (using materializecss)

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I am currently using the `materializecss` framework and pulling in an icon and putting it beside a text. I need to align the text in the middle **above** the icon with css but what I currently have does not seem to be working.

```
<table class="centered">
    <thead>
        <th class="align-text"><i class="material-icons small">timer</i>Time</th>
        <th>Another header</th>
        <th>And another header</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

my `css` file at the moment:

```
.align-text {
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

However, the text still stays to the right of icon.

This is the result that I am ultimately trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: is that what you need ? http://plnkr.co/edit/sUxq40VIxfr2Im3Uq2rm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: Here's what you need ^_^ **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ixSyi8dNubq62ZpPopQ?p=preview)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <style>
    th {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .align-text {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

  <table class="centered">
    <thead>
      <th class="align-text"><span>Time</span><i class="material-icons small">timer</i>
      </th>
      <th class="align-text"><span>Time</span><i class="material-icons small">timer</i>
      </th>
      <th class="align-text"><span>Time</span><i class="material-icons small">timer</i>
      </th>
    </thead>
  </table>

  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Microsmsm however, this does not seem to work with my current setup. I have edited my post to include what the icon is wrapped in. The problem is that the table headers `<th>` equally space itself out with the other table headers. I can not hardcode the width and height of the table header

Comment: @Simon is that what you need ? http://plnkr.co/edit/frPWZgeUajpDy1ZEuwdp?p=preview

Comment: thank you that displays the results yes, but when I put it into `<tr>` table row and have multiple headers (as in my example) it does not work.

Comment: It works for me ! can you edit your question and provide some screenshots and some more code please so we can help @Simon ?

Comment: I have edited the picture to show what is required. Essentially have the 3 table headers with the text above the icon. In the provided code you showed me, I add `<tr>` inside `<thead>` then duplicate `<th>` to simulate another header. They stack on top instead of being inline another column

Comment: I have updated the answer ^_^ please tell me if it works

Comment: Thank you, this works but, now it messes up the original table format and everything is not automatically spaced apart equally. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: please join here to let me know where the error ^_^ ! http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=streamer&s=4p9nj2jdD7ClLSQh